# Get user Mobile Number using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

How to get the user mobile number using Facebook javascript SDK?

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a site where you can just ask for working code without putting some effort into it yourself, first. Please show us a sample of your attempt at solving this issue, so we can help you complete it.

Comment: We can get user details by below code, but how to get user mobile noFB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {if (response.authResponse) {FB.api('/me', function (me) {alert(me.name);alert(me.email);alert(me.first_name);document.getElementById('lbllname').innerHTML = me.last_name;})}});}

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the mobile number of Facebook users. There's no field in the Graph API for that.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/#fields

Comment: But i heard that we can get it if a user provides it as public

Comment: @MahaDev I heard a lot of things too... If it's not listed as available field in the docs you won't be able to retrieve it from the Graph API. Simple as that.